# how much disk space is needed for vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

we are installing it on a box that doesn't have much space and we can't seem to find the required disk space requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0" is  700Mb on my machine with C++ and c# installed.
Figure a Gb with any stuff it's stuck somewhere else and MSDN.

Answer (score 5):

The box ([and MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/vstudio/products/bb894726%28en-us%29.aspx)) says 2.2GB, but that's probably for full install with the MSDN stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a very unscientific survey of my dev PC tells me it uses 1.67 Gb.

Depends which options you install, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

The min system requirements can be found [Professional Edition system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/professional/default.mspx)

> Hardware requirements:
>
> Minimum: 2.0 GHz CPU, 512 MB RAM, 8 GB HDD
>
> Recommended: 2.6 GHz CPU, 1 GB RAM, 20 GB HDD

The min is really 8gb, your forgetting the space you need to run it, compile, sql databases, etc that sort of thing.